# Swift 4 - Issue with ObjectMapper while parsing JSON

Tags: ios11, swift4, xcode9, objectmapper

My code was working perfectly before Swift 4, I am just parsing a simple JSON file, and I am mapping everything into my model class.

Here is my example code :

First of all I get my json file.

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myFile", ofType: "json") { }
```

Then I can parse it.

```
do {
       let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: NSData.ReadingOptions.mappedIfSafe)
       let json = JSON(data: jsonData)

       if let jsonZones = json["zones"].array {
          let parsedZones = Mapper<Zone>().mapArray(JSONObject: jsonZones.description)
          parsedZones?.forEach({ (element) -> Void in
              // Do stuff...
          })
 }
```

Now I can show you my Zone class

```
class Zone: Object, Mappable {

    @objc dynamic var code: String?

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
        mapping(map: map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        code <- map["code"]
    }
```

You will also need my to see my JSON file :

```
{
    "info": {
        ....
        ....
    },
    "zones": [{
        "code": "EN"
    }],
}
```

I am crashing because parsedZones is nil. 
I know I can check for nil but it was working on Swift 3 and I modified nothing before converting to Swift 4.
Regarding my JSON file, it shouldn't be nil.

Can I have some help?

Comment: `JSONEncoder/Decoder` in Swift 4 makes `ObjectMapper` pretty much obsolete ;)

Comment: Can you be more specific @vadian? I am very interested

Comment: Please watch the WWDC videos about What‘s new in Swift and Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use like this :

```
if let jsonZones = json["zones"].arrayObject {
    let parsedZones = Mapper<Zone>().mapArray(JSONObject: jsonZones)
    parsedZones?.forEach({ (element) -> Void in
        print(element.code)
    })
}
```